# What determines the pressure in the system when the gas tanks are opened?

Tags: experimental-chemistry

I have two gas tanks of nitrogen and oxygen. Mixture of gases is created at specified composition and used in the system of interest.

Let's say I want to create an atmospheric conditions in my system, mass ratio of oxygen to nitrogen is 0.3 and total pressure of 1 bar (oxygen partial pressure 0.21 bar). Therefore, mass flow ratio of the gases needs to be 0.3 to create a gas mixture of atmospheric composition. Gas tanks are equipped with volumetric flowmeters. This isn't a problem as mass and volumetric flowrates can be easily related by the ideal gas law. I'm planning using air at atmospheric pressure and temperatures 500-800 $^\circ$C which I think justifies ideal gas law.

What I'm not clear about is when the tanks are opened and the flowrates are specified, what will determine the pressure in the system? This is important as I need to know and change the oxygen partial pressure during this experiment (electrical conductivity relaxation).

Schematic is provided to give a better insight into the process: [image]

Comment: Hi! I may help you but I have some doubts. You start with two tanks, open their valves, and then both streams enter a *third* tank/vessel? Is the third vessel closed?

Comment: I have understood it as an open system at ambient pressure, being flushed by some flow of artificial air. So N and O  pressure are such that maintain the required respective flows or flow ratio against atmospheric pressure. Right or wrong ?

Comment: @MetalStorm The system (vessel) is opened as gases flow in and out of it. I added schematic of the process in the main post. Flowrates of gases can be controlled.

Comment: Flow in vs flow out. I would use mass flow controllers and a butterfly valve on the outlet controlled by a barotron.

Comment: To get mass flow rate from volumetric, pressure and temperature are required. These are constants in the experiment, but would like to know what sets pressure in this setup.

Comment: @DarioMirić Great, just one last question. The vessel is attached to an electrical furnace, so we have an exchange of energy between it and the air within the vessel. Is that correct?

Comment: @MetalStorm Yes.